# Device adaptation: how to hide an UI element for a specific device type on UI5

Tags: sapui5

I want to adjust some parts of UI based on a device type (desktop, tablet, phone).
According to [Step 36: Device Adaptation](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/topic/d63a15e5eebb45cdada317bae5f45bc2), I have to:

1. Specify a device model:

```js
const oDeviceModel = new JSONModel(Device);
oDeviceModel.setDefaultBindingMode("OneWay");
this.setModel(oDeviceModel, "device")
```

2. Apply `sapUiVisibleOnlyOnDesktop`/`sapUiHideOnDesktop` to the `class` property of the desired UI5-element.

Unfortunately, such approach didn't work out for [`IconTabFilter`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.IconTabFilter) and I've succeeded to solve the issue with the `visible = "{= !${device>/system/phone} }"` XML-template expression.

Although my approach works, I'm not sure if it's a recommended way to solve the task. Perhaps, there is some better option how to hide an UI element for a specific device type on UI5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the expression binding for "visible" is the "best-practice" solution to your problem.

It is explicitly mentioned in the latest UI5 openSAP course [Evolved Web Apps with SAPUI5](https://open.sap.com/courses/ui52) (week 2 - unit 3).

Comment: So, it looks like `visible = "{= !${device>/system/phone} }"` is the best-practice. Thanks for referencing to the specific place in the video course.